# JS import is stopping rest of script from running

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a simple script that I'm trying to run that imports a JS file and then does a console log. The issue I'm having is that the import statement seems to stop the rest of the code from running without giving any sort of error. The code:

```html
<script type="module">
    import { Engine } from './engine/Engine.js'

    (function() {
        console.log('a');
    })();
</script>
```

If I comment out the import line the console log works fine.

EDIT: Engine.js source

```html
import { EngineError } from './errors/EngineError.js';
import { Screen } from './screen/Screen.js';


export class Engine {
    constructor(reportErrors) {
        // Set default values
        this.Error = new EngineError(reportErrors);
        this.FPS = 60;

        this.Screen = new Screen(this);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Outputted HTML

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./engine/engine.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Body</h1>
    <canvas id="game"></canvas>

    <script type="module">
        import { Engine } from './engine/Engine.js'
        //import { Screen } from './engine/screen/Screen.js';

        (function() {
            console.log('a');
        })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: @LloydFrancis There is no error. No console output at all including the log

Comment: Check for Network activity? I guess your import is hitting a not found response.

Comment: Strange, the JS file isn't being pulled in at all. Only the HTML and a CSS file are being loaded. Going straight to it's URL though does load the correct file so it does exist on the system

Comment: You are using a relative PATH. Check this page's current URL  path vs the PATH the file is available at. But checking the network pane should be easier because it will tell you where the browser is reaching.

Comment: @enapupe I need to use the relative path as I'm opening the HTML file in the browser rather than setting up a vhost ect. The CSS file that I'm loading is also using the relative path and working just fine and if I try and open the JS that also loads the file

Comment: I'm not telling you to not use it. Just to be aware of it. I need you to check your network activity and see if the files is being requested successfully. If so, please share its contents.

Comment: @enapupe Nope the Engine.js file isn't being loaded at all. I've edited my question to include this file but I don't think that will help to fix the issue as it works on a different machine.

Comment: Ok then you gotta share your network activity with us.. It's not yet clear if the browser is firing a request for this file or not.

Comment: @enapupe https://imgur.com/a/83AIoNM There's a link to my network tab. As I said a few times, there is no request for the Engine.js file.

Comment: That's very unlikely. If I run your first snippet I see a request for that file. Also, you shared just a poor amount of information from your network tab, filters and such aren't visible.

Comment: @enapupe It may be unlikely but it's what's happening. Image with filters: https://imgur.com/a/YplX0ZC

Comment: Ok so if you isolated code works then you gotta check what else is there. Could you share the full html output of that page in question?

Comment: @enapupe Editted my question to include the `test.html` source